# Not sure what I'm missing here? C#(30 Days of Code Challenge; Intro to Conditional Statements)

Tags: c#

Here is the problem:

Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:

If  is odd, print Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of  to , print Not Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of  to , print Weird
If  is even and greater than , print Not Weird

Complete the stub code provided in your editor to print whether or not  is weird.

Input Format: A single line containing a positive integer, N.

Constraints: `1 <= n <= 100`

Output Format
Print `"Weird"` if the number is weird; otherwise, print `"Not Weird"`

Explanation:
Sample Case 0: n=3

n is odd and odd numbers are weird, so we print Weird

Sample Case 1: n = 24
n>20 and n is even, so it isn't weird. Thus we print Not Weird.

I've done stuff like this before but I'm not sure what is missing.

It passes Test cases 0,1,4,5,6 but fails 2, 3,and 7.
Test Case 2 is 4 and nothing happens
Test Case 3 is 18 and nothing happens
Test Case 7 is 20 and nothing happens

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter:");
int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (N % 2 == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Weird");
}
else if (N % 2 == 0 && (N <= 2 && N >= 5))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Weird");
}
else if (N % 2 == 0 && (N <= 6 && N >= 20))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Weird");
}

else if (N % 2 == 0 && N > 20)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Weird");
}
```

Case 2 is 4 = "Not Weird"
Case 3 is 18 = "Weird"
Case 7 is 20 = "Weird"

Comment: `N <= 2 && N >= 5` is impossible. Something cannot be both less than or equal to `2` AND greater than or equal to `5`. Same with `<= 6 && >= 20`

Comment: You also don't have to check for all the conditions. Just check for the "weird" (or "not weird") condition, and use an `else` for the rest. For example: `if (N % 2 == 1 || (N >= 6 && N <= 20)) Console.WriteLine("Weird"); else Console.WriteLine("Not Weird");`

Comment: (N <= 2 && N >= 5) and (N <= 6 && N >= 20) are not possible. Use || (OR operator) instead.

Comment: @Yohan - The else if statements don't actually make sense with OR operations. I started to say this at first until I read the N <= 2 && N >= 5 followed by N <= 6 && N >= 20. Switching these to || doesn't make much sense and fails for Case 2 (N = 4), which should print "Not Weird"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cases are impossible. For example...

```
        else if (N % 2 == 0 && (N <= 6 && N >= 20))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weird");
        }
```

will never happen. You're looking for numbers that are <= 6 AND >= 20. Not sure from your description, but it sounds like you might need to switch the order - example:

```
        else if (N % 2 == 0 && (N >= 6 && N <= 20))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weird");
        }
```

Furthermore, since you've already determined the number is even from the first if statement, you can simplify a little bit.

```
        else if (N >= 6 && N <= 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weird");
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I see the problem now,  Thank you so much for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(N <= 1|| N >= 100){
        Console.WriteLine("Number can not be less then 1 and bigger then 100");
    }
    else{
        string evenOdd = N % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
        if(evenOdd == "even"){
            if(N >=2 || N <= 5){
                Console.WriteLine("Not Weird");
            }
            else if(N >= 6 || N <= 20){
                Console.WriteLine("Weird");
            }
            else{
                Console.WriteLine("Not Weird");
            }
            
        } 
        if(evenOdd == "odd"){
            Console.WriteLine("Weird");
        }
    }
```

First check if the input number (in this case is N) is greater than 100 and less than 0. After that, declare string variable and at the same time initialize with ternary operation, which makes a check "whether it is even or odd" (here I called her "evenOdd"). If is even, then the value of "evenOdd" will be even and vice versa. Because the task requirement is (if is even and N >= 2 and N <= 5 print "Not Weird", N >= 6 and N <= 20 print "Weird", N >= 20 print "Not Weird" and also if it is "even" print "Not Weird" and "odd" print "Weird", first check if "evenOdd" is "even" inside in this "if", I do the remaining checks (N >= 2 or N <= 5 print  "Not Weird" and so on) and after (evenOdd is even) I do another check (if evenOdd is odd print "Weird"). In short: N if is 6, will check the first check and return "false", then will enter in "else". Because 6 is "even", then the value of "evenOdd will be "even" and will enter the first "if, because in the first check it is greater than 5, return false, since it is 6, it will enter the next check, which returns true and will print "Weird".

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry about that. I answer for the first time. I do not have much experience. Thank you for the advice. I hope it is good now.